# I have two problems ( SEO )

Tags: author, seo, google-search

how are you ?

In my website I want to make the author's page and category(slug of it is country)  to be in google reslut ..

like this : http://rehlat-world.com/profile/saqaf , but when I search in google : [site:rehlat-world.com](http://www.google.com.sa/search?q=site%3arehlat-world.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&client=firefox-a&rlz=1R1GGLL_ar___SA419&safe=active) , I didn't find authors page.

how can include authors page in google result , this is [my robort](http://rehlat-world.com/robots.txt) and this is my [sitemap](http://rehlat-world.com/sitemap.xml)

note: I change the slug of author ( http://rehlat-world.com/author/** from author to profile ( http://rehlat-world.com/profile/** ) ..

how can include author page in google result ?

ALSO , when I search in google (site:rehlat-world.com) some of posts repeated like this :

http://rehlat-world.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%AF-%D8%AC%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A9-%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AD%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%85%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9-%D8%AC2.html

http://rehlat-world.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%AF-%D8%AC%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A9-%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AD%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%85%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9-%D8%AC2.html?replytocom=37

same reslut but change in the last of like "?replaytocom=37" WHY?

Comment: The long links that you see repeated are comments. The numbers/percent signs are url encoded forms of the arabic alphabet. the ReplyToCom=x is the comment #. This looks like it has to do with your theme since my theme uses anchor tags instead of a querystring.

Comment: I know the long link (arabic link) but ?replaytocom=* how can remove it from google result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your author pages are marked with the noindex tag, look at the page source:

It must be a plugin that is doing that, that is not the default setting.

If you don't want the duplicate pages, try a plugin like Yoast WordPress SEO that let you add Nofollow to comment links.

Comment: this is the source of author page 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow" />

Comment: Do you mean this?

Comment: wow thank you very much , I found the problem , I probram new fucntion if is_author echo <meta ..... > .. thank you very mcuh